# How to convert from Shia to Sunni?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, sunni, shiism

I am to marry a Muslim man. I am Sunni Muslim but he is Shia Muslim. We have both realized this is a problem and that the sects are generally against each other. There have even been some political issues. My family is not keen on letting me marry a Shia man, but he and I are both Muslim and we are looking for a way for him to convert to the Sunni sect, or anything that can help. He is not strongly bonded to the Shia sect at all or its beliefs. He is more leaning on the Sunni side.

I hope it is not haram for me to marry a Shia man. My biggest concern is what he can do; how he can join the Sunni sect?

Comment: Sect is not religion. You don't need to convert to a sect, just start believing in it.

Comment: Sit down with your parents. Ask them what they define in a Muslim, I suppose as a Sunni it would be to follow the Sunnah of the prophet and the Qur'an. All Shias agree to such. Hence it shouldn't be a problem. Perhaps your father can ask him a few questions about the two. That being said, Shia or not, your father's permission is required. So that is something you must resolve

Answer (score 2):

From the rules of both Sunni and Shia Islam, marriage between Sunni and Shia Muslim is allowed, and Sunni nikah is also recognized valid in Shia Islam; so it is not compulsory to change from this point.

If your future groom wants to change to Sunni belief and practice, there's no formal reversion needed. Practice is different in many details, and rules differ as well. So, if he wants to join the Sunni community, he would best contact the imam to learn the basics.

If he would only do so for you, he may better stay in his community and speak to your father as to what is important to him as your husband.

Answer (score 0):

He needs to change his beliefs that Ali is just a sahabi as are Omar and Abu Bakr, and follow the quran and the Sunnah, pray five times a day like sunni people etc.

Answer (score -1):

As long as your husband follows what the Sunni sect teaches and has the intention that he has Sunni then he can consider himself Sunni. Make sure you follow the obligations of marriage when marrying him though.

Answer (score -1):

I know countless Sunni people married to Shia people, there is no conflict or obstacles whatsoever, except for the emotional ones that depend on your personalities. If you love each and willing to accept technical difference, nothing will -or should- come in your way.